# How can I get a color map from a list?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I am beginner developer and I encountered a problem.

I tried to plot using matplotlib in python with different colors.
I depicted the problem I have as simple as possible below.

```
list = [5,4,8]
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [1,2,3,4]

for i in range(len(list)):
   plt.plot((x[i], x[i+1]), (y[i], y[i+1]), color = ?list?)
```

As you notice, there are three different straight lines.
I want to color them with different colors.
Ultimately, I want to convert the above list into a color map or a cmap which are available to
apply for matplotlib.plot.

Sorry for my humble english. I hope experts in stackoverflow help me for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid naming a variable `list`, as this is the Python command to make a list.
You could pick colors from the [list of named colors](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html):

```py
color_list = ['tomato', 'gold', 'orchid']

for i in range(len(color_list)):
   plt.plot((x[i], x[i+1]), (y[i], y[i+1]), color=color_list[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, mind that `list` is a bad variable name because it conflicts with the function `list()` ant the type `list` in python.
Second, iterating over a `range(len(variable))` is ok but less pythonic than iterating over `enumerate(variable)`.

As for the color part, you can use [HTML color names](https://htmlcolors.com/color-names), hex codes, or rgb values as valid colors.

```
colors = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'orange']
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [1,2,3,4]

for i, c in enumerate(colors):
    plt.plot((x[i], x[i]+1), (y[i], y[i]+1), color=c)
plt.show()
```

Which output this

[image]